# Better way to write this code

Tags: ruby, user-interface, graphics, interface, menu

I am designing a user interface for a menu project. I tried using a `for`-loop such as:

```
for i in 0..8
    i=i
end
for k in 0..7
    k=k
end

if @selection==i && @unlock==k && $switches[(what do I do here?)]==?????
do thing
```

Whenever the user presses the Y key, it will turn off a function; if `@selection==1` is highlighted and the user presses the "Y" key, the corresponding switch at that specific location should be turned off. `@unlock` is just used as a way of saying that, unless this global boolean is set to true, the user can press "Y" and turn this switch on or off.

Comment: First of all, you can replace all statements like `foo==true` with `foo` and those like `foo==false` with `!foo`

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you could change each if else to something like this:

```
BITMAP_PATH = "Graphics/Pictures/Input Map/switch"
if @selection==1 && @unlock1
  pbSEPlay("BW2MenuChoose",65)
  bitmap_switch = $switches[310] ? 'off' : 'on' # sets path to off/on
  @graphics["switch"].setBitmap(BITMAP_PATH + bitmap_switch)
  !$switches[310] # it changes value of boolean to opposite value
end
```

And the selections that only have one condition could be written like this:

```
if @selection==0 && @unlock0
 pbSEPlay("buzzer",65)
end
```

You could also try writing a case expression for @selection. Probably you could dry it even more, but I do not really understand what each @unlock is used for.

**Edit:**

```
  BITMAP_PATH = "Graphics/Pictures/Input/switch"
  SELECTION_SWITCHES = [nil, 310, 300, 339, 338, 330, 318]
  def pbChangeSwitch
    case 
    when 0
      case @selection
      when 0,7
        pbSEPlay("buzzer",65) if instance_variable_get("@unlock#{@selection}")
      when 1..6
        if instance_variable_get("@unlock#{@selection}")
          pbSEPlay("BW2MenuChoose",65)
          bitmap_switch = $switches[SELECTION_SWITCHES[@selection]] ? 'off' : 'on'
          @sprites["switch"].setBitmap(BITMAP_PATH + bitmap_switch)
          index = SELECTION_SWITCHES[@selection]
          $switches[index] = !$switches[index]
        end
      end
      Graphics.update
```

Please add `$` to the last line. `bitmap_switch` can not be `true` or `false`, because you add it to `BITMAP_PATH`, so it has to be 'off' or 'on'.

Comment: The unlock is a boolean I set at the beginning of a method from the same class that basically acts as a way of saying if this switch HAS been turned on, then this boolean will remain on. Normally in an else statement where if the switch is turned off so would unlock, but instead I just have it stay on always. Also, I did end up using one with a case @selection, but I'm genuinely confused if this would apply to it with the new code you introduced: https://i.gyazo.com/fdc7606d40744a0c11aa3e613b329a58.png

Comment: I am sorry, I used `@switches` instead of `$switches` in the `bitmap_switch`. You can also write `when 1..6` instead of `1,2,3...`

Comment: You could also use [`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) for @unlock. `instance_variable_get("@unlock#{@selection}")`

Comment: The only issue that remains now is that there are multiple Switches that must be turned on/off, depending on what selection you are currently at, because $switches[310] only corresponds to selection==1. selection==2 corresponds to $switches[300], which makes it difficult for my to use a for loop with, since they're not ordered in a way that I can take advantage of: https://i.gyazo.com/164e08ab3fe419219f5d7334aabde0c1.png

Comment: How would I call that exactly is the main concern that I have? I've never done something like this before, so this is all new to me and exciting in a way. So I guess I should ask, where I would I call it at and how would I call it?

Comment: Mind uploading the code from your photo to your post so I can modify it?

Comment: Here is the code: https://i.gyazo.com/806efdde885745d5ba28cb2192b5b849.png

the switches in question that correspond to a specific selection is:

s3 corresponds to 339, s4 is 338, s5 is 330, s6 is 318

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong with that hash idea. You can create an Array `SELECTION_SWITCHES = [nil, 310, 300, 339, 338, 330, 318]` and then use it like this: `$switches[SELECTION_SWITCHES[@selection]]`

Comment: Note that on 3-5 lines can be changed to: `pbSEPlay("buzzer",65) if instance_variable_get("@unlock#{@selection}")`

Comment: I was thinking a similar thing with an array, but I always had a hard time figuring out what to do to make that work. This seems like a pretty interesting way of going about doing this, with minimal copy/pastes. Because otherwise it would've ended up like my previous program that was 10000 lines of code, because I didn't know any of these shortcuts.

But, I will test this out, once I get back from class and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Alright, so I used the script and for the most part it doesn't really change the UI. I noticed that you set the switch to check if it is "off" or "on", which it should be false/true. Also, I forgot to mention that there are 2 graphics for the bitmap 'switch'. One that has the .png name switchoff, and one called switchon.

The thing is, it works, as the sound effect plays on certain selections, but the graphics don't change and the switches don't actually turn on/off when the Y key is pressed.

Comment: It's strange, it still doesn't exactly seem to work. However, if I do take out bitmap_switch, the graphics do change as they should. But, when I check the switches in debug, they still have not changed, as the $switches are still set to true, when they should be set to false, and vice versa when the Y key is pressed.

Also, what does !$switches mean exactly? This is also new to me as I've never seen it done like this before.

Comment: OH man, I guess I am not thinking straight today.  It should be `$switches =  !$switches`.

Comment: `!` acts like `not`. So when switch is true, it returns false.

Comment: One slight error that I caught and I think you forgot to add was [SELECTION_SWITCHES[@selection]] to the end of $switches, because now it works like a dream!

I must say thank you, sir, you are a gentleman and a scholar, and you have taught me quite a few handy tricks that I know will be useful for me later on! This saved me a lot of headache and motivation burning to get this done. There are some slight modifications that I will also have to include, but for now this works exactly as I had hoped!

Thank you, once again!

Comment: I added it to my original post. Sorry it took so many tries, but I am happy you did it :)